# Recommended Maven package structure?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, build-process, directory-structure

Is there a standard/recommended format to follow when creating packages in a maven project? I understand that the directory structure is supposed to follow a proscribed format and wasn't sure what the best way is to insert my packages.

Should my package structure be `main.java.com.foo.bar` and `test.java.com.foo.bar` or remove the beginning and then have `com.foo.bar` and `com.foo.bar.test`?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: You could have just googled this -- it's in the standard docs as well as in (too) many SO questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main` and `test` do not belong to the **package name**. You would put classes and tests in the same package (i.e. no additional `test` in the package name; `com.mycompany.app` in the example below), but distributed to `main` and `test` **directory** respectively.

Example for a project structure (taken from [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)):

```
my-app 
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

Answer (score 4):

Your package structure should be like this:

```
com.foo.bar
```

which means in directory layout:

```
src
 +-- main
 !    +-- java
 !          +-- com
 !               +-- foo
 !                    +-- bar
 !                         +-- MyFirstClass.java
 +-- test
      +-- java
            +-- com
                 +-- foo
                      +-- bar
                           +-- MyFirstClassTest.java
```